# Heroku deploy failed: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my Python app to Heroku. I am using pipenv. I have defined Pipfile:

```
...
[packages]
django = "*"
...
```

I defined Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn scrapper.wsgi
clock: python scrapper/scheduler.py
```

I also added config variable for settings:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:         scrapper.settings
```

When i push my changes to Heroku, deply fails with the following error:

> File "manage.py", line 17, in 
> "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: You can check the deployment log to check whether Django is installed or not

Comment: How do I see this? heroku logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Django installed by writing this command :

```
python -m django --version
```

if it's not installed you can install it by writing this command :

```
pip install django
```

Comment: If you would read the question you would notice that I already did install django

Comment: You may need to add Django to "requirements.txt file" by writing this command : 
"pip freeze > requirements.txt " .
And also try to activate your virtual environment "venv" before pushing to Heroku